# Using "anti-dots" in stars and bars questions

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of solutions to
$$x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_5 = 26$$
where
$x_k \leq 6$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,5$.

This is the solution.
Use the usual stars and bars method except fix every bin with $6$ dots so it looks like
$$......|......|......|......|...... $$

Since $30-26=4$, then we want to place $4$ anti-dots into these places so that eahc bins have in total $24$ dots.
It looks like to me that it must be $\binom{5}4$... but the answer has $\binom{8}4$. I don't see how.

Comment: Why do you compute $30-24$?  Didn't you mean to compute $30-26$?

Comment: Yes sorry, my bad. I was fixing up the quetsion and forogt that in there.

Comment: Well, using Stars and Bars, you want to count the ways to get $5$ non-negative integers that sum to $4$.  That's $\binom {5+4-1}{5-1}=\binom 84$.

Comment: Thanks. But visually we only have 5 spots to place $4$ anti dots in right? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Look up [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)). The connection to the binomial symbol is spelled out pretty clearly in that article.